# How to handle ostream operator overloading inside templated class

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading, ostream

So I have this templated class called list

```
//List.h
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H
#include<fstream>

template <class T>
class List
{
    private:
        struct ListNode
        {
           T value;
           ListNode* next;
           ListNode* prev;

           ListNode(T value1, ListNode* next1 = NULL, ListNode* prev1 = NULL)
           {
            value = value1;
            next = next1;
            prev = prev1;
           }
        };
        ListNode* head;
        ListNode* tail;

   public:
       List() {head = NULL; tail = NULL;};
       ~List();
       void PrintForward(std::ostream &out);
       void PrintBackward(std::ostream &out);
       void InsertFront(const T &item);
       void InsertRear(const T &item);
       bool InsertAsNth(int N, const T &item);
       bool DeleteFront(T &val);
       bool DeleteRear(T &val);
       bool DeleteNth(int N, T &val);
       int DeleteAllOccur(const T &item);

       std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, List::ListNode const* p);

};
#endif
```

Now I have been trying to get this to compile but with no success. I know it has to do with the way I have the ostream operator overloaded but unfortunately I really do not know/could not find a better way.

also this is my compiler error

```
 warning C4346: 'List<T>::ListNode' : dependent name is not a type prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
```

Comment: @hetepeperfan
I also tried what you said and it worked though now I have another interesting compiler error saying binary 'operator <<' has too many parameters

Comment: That's because you've defined it to take three parameters: a `List` (which becomes `this`), an `std::ostream` and a `List::ListNode`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, List::ListNode const* p);
```

has to become

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, typename List::ListNode const* p);
```

or maybe even

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, typename List<T>::ListNode const* p);
```

to be more explicit.

Because `::ListNode` is a dependant type of the templated class `List` and the C++ compiler needs a little hint there. The warning is actually surprisingly helpful in this case, which cannot be said for many template related ones :)

Comment: Wow, I cant believe I missed that. Many apologies for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error says exactly what is wrong and what you have to do: `List<T>::Node` is a qualified-id dependent on a template parameter, so the compiler cant be sure if `Node` is a type or a value. So you have to write `typename` before it to tell the compiler that `Node` is a type.

I suggest you to checkout this question: [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two major problems with your code.  The most
critical is that you are making `operator<<` a member, and
trying to give it three parameters, Which is completely illegal.
If the first parameter is to be an `std::ostream&`, there is no
way you can define it as a member; it must be a free function.
If it also needs access to private data, then you'll have to
make it a friend.  But be aware:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&, typename List::ListNode const* );
```

makes a non-template function friend.  A different non-template
function for each instantiation of the template.  This is rarely
what is wanted.  You can make a specific template instantiation
friend, but only if the template function is declared before
hand.  Which is impossible in this case, because one of the
arguments of the function has a nested type.  The more idiomatic
way of solving this (in my experience, anyway) is to define the
friend inline:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& dest, typename List::ListNode const& p )
{
    //  ...
}
```

In this case, `operator<<` is also a non-templated function, but
the definition is nested in the class template, so you will get
a new instance of the function automatically.